# Calculating the principal curvature of the geodesic sphere of radius $r$ in the space of dimension $n$ and of constant sectional curvature $c$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, geodesics

I'm reading "Riemannian Geometry" by Manfredo P. do Carmo and I'm trying to calculate the principal curvature of the geodesic sphere of radius $r$ in the space of dimension $n$ and of constant sectional curvature $c$. So far, I can only calculate the case where $c=0$. For the cases where $c<0$ and $c>0$, I'm confused and don't know how to start.

Denote by $\overline M$ the space of dimension $n$ and of constant sectional curvature $c$, and by $M$ the geodesic sphere of radius $r$. Then
$$\overline M=\left\{ \begin{array}{lll} \mathbb R^n & c=0,  \\ \mathbb S^n(c) & c>0,  \\ \mathbb H^n(c) & c<0. \end{array} \right.$$
According to "Riemannian Geometry" by Manfredo P. do Carmo, principal curvatures are the eigenvalues of shape operator.

For the case where $c=0$, let's first consider $r=1$. let $p\in M$, $x\in T_pM$ and $\eta\in(T_pM)^\bot$, $|\eta|=1$. Let $N$ be a local extension of $\eta$ normal to $M$. Then
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
   S_\eta(x)&=-\left(\overline\nabla_xN\right)^T\\
   &=-\left(\overline\nabla_{X^i\partial_i}N^j\partial_j\right)^T\\
   &=-\left(X^i\partial_i(N^j)\partial_j\right)^T\\
   &=-\left(X^i\partial_i(N^j)\partial_j-\left\langle X^i\partial_i(N^j)\partial_j , N^k\partial_k\right\rangle N^l\partial_l\right)\\
   &=-\left(X^i\delta_i^j\partial_j-(X^i\delta_i^j N^k\delta_{jk})(N^l\partial_l)\right)\\
   &=-\left(X^i\partial_i-\left(\sum_i X^i N^i\right)\left(N^l\partial_l\right)\right)\\
   &=-X^i\partial_i\\
   &=-x.
   \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Therefore, all the principal curvatures of the sphere of radius $1$ in $\mathbb R^n$ with respect to the outward pointing unit normal $N=N^j\partial_j$ are $-1$. If the radius is $r$, then $N=\frac1r N^j\partial_j$, so the principal curvatures are $-\frac1r$. If the normal direction is inward, then $N=-\frac1r N^j\partial_j$, so the principal curvatures are $\frac1r$. This finishes the case where $c=0$.

For the cases where $c<0$ and $c>0$, the choice of frame $\partial_i$, the choice of unit normal vector field $N$, and the calculation of connection $\overline\nabla$ are quite complicated. Can someone give me a hint or answer? Any help would be appreciated!